# Как пополнять внутреннюю валюту в приложении?

Tags: java, android

В первый раз реализую внутренние покупки в приложении и встретился с проблемой. Не могу понять, в приложении есть своя валюта. Мне необходима возможность ее пополнения, смотрю на виды контента в play-e вижу контролируемое гуглом и подписка. Контролируемое написано приобретается единожды. Подписка как полагаю тоже не подходит. Вопрос как реализуется такая фича?

Comment: У них же в доках [все написано](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Consume)

Comment: покупаете контролируемое, и сразу его "консьюмите".

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понял куда копать